# Concatenating Flows in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, apache-kafka-streams, akka-http

We are using Kafka and are looking to use [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) to get access to data in our state stores. We have an existing service which uses Akka HTTP to serve up a REST API, and we wanted to integrate interactive queries into the flow.

It seemed like [kafka-streams-query](https://github.com/lightbend/kafka-streams-query) would be a perfect fit for this. However, it integrates into Akka HTTP by exposing a `route` property that uses the low-level API, which maps to a `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any]`. All of our previous code concatenates code using Akka HTTP's routing DSL.

I would expect code like the following to work, but it doesn't:

```scala
implicit val system:ActorSystem = ActorSystem("web")
implicit val materializer:ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val firstRoutes:Route = ... //a route object populated
val lastRoutes:Route = ... //other route object populad

val iqServiceFlow:Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] = ...// code that returns the interactive query service

val firstFlow = Route.handlerFlow(firstRoutes)
val lastFlow = Route.handlerFlow(lastRoutes)

// The following code doesn't work though everything I've seen online suggests it should
val handler = firstFlow via iqServiceFlow via lastFlow

Http().bindAndHandle(handler, "0.0.0.0", 8000)
```

How can I combine flows in Akka Streams?

**Edit**:
Corrected the handler assignment statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For clarity, let's start by making all the return types explicit:

```scala
val iqServiceFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] = ...
val firstFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed] = Route.handlerFlow(firstRoutes)
val lastFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed]  = Route.handlerFlow(lastRoutes)
```

Also, instead of...

```scala
val handler = firstRoutes via iqServiceFlow via lastFlow
```

...you probably meant:

```scala
val handler = firstFlow via iqServiceFlow via lastFlow
```

In order to chain flows together with `via`, the input and output types must match: that is, the output type of the first flow must be the same as the input type of the second flow, and so on. What you're trying to do with your handler is the following:

```scala
[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // firstFlow
                   |
                   v
             [HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // iqServiceFlow
                                |
                                v
                          [HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // lastFlow
```

The output type of all your flows is `HttpResponse`, but their respective input types are all `HttpRequest`, so you cannot chain them together with `via`.

To chain your flows, you need a function that somehow converts a `HttpResponse` to an `HttpRequest`:

```scala
val respToReq: HttpResponse => HttpRequest = ...
```

You can create a flow from the above function:

```scala
val convertingFlow: Flow[HttpResponse, HttpRequest] = Flow.fromFunction(respToReq)
```

Now you can chain your flows:

```scala
val handler = firstFlow via convertingFlow via iqServiceFlow via convertingFlow via lastFlow
```

The types align as follows:

```scala
[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // firstFlow
                   |
                   v
             [HttpResponse, HttpRequest] // convertingFlow
                                |
                                v
                           [HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // iqServiceFlow
                                              |
                                              v
                                        [HttpResponse, HttpRequest] // convertingFlow
                                                            |
                                                            v                              
                                                      [HttpRequest, HttpResponse] // lastFlow
```

The above assumes that you can reuse the same conversion function/flow. If this assumption doesn't hold, you can obviously create different conversion functions/flows.